# ROR Backend - Android App Error ActionCableException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api, redis, actioncable

**RubyOnRails** APIs are using `ActionCable` to connect to the socket for live tracking.

There are two **Android** apps Driver and Customer. Drivers are broadcasting their locations and customers are subscribing.

Sometimes everything looks fine on the apps and backend but the maximum time apps start throwing the error while connecting the action cable:

> > ActionCableException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

**RubyOnRails** Application is deployed over the Nginx and passenger.

Here are the logs I am getting

> > error ignoring messages processed after the websocket was closed

Please help me to know the reason and some solution to overcome from here.

Thanks.